# InfluxDB - Getting only last value in query

Tags: influxdb

Is possible to query only for the last value (or n-th value) of the results of a query?

For example, in the query:

```
SELECT value FROM response_times WHERE time > now() - 1h limit 1000;
```

Is possible to get only the last value, i.e. the one more far ago in time (possibly the 1000-th element)?

Of course I can retrieve them all and then skip to the last one, but I don't want to waste bandwith this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the API, have a look at first/last to select the first or last record of a column. 
You also have top/bottom to select more than one record

[edit] top/bottom seem to return higest/lowest values of the time frame

Comment: Where is this documented? I cannot find it at http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/querying_data.html or http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/query_language.html

Comment: For 0.8 it's in the aggregate functions : http://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/api/aggregate_functions.html#first/last sorry to not have provided the link before !

Comment: I'm most interested in getting the times for the first/last values...any way to do that?

Answer (score 52):

If you are using InfluxDB 0.8 dont use **FIRST()** or **LAST()** if you have not **GROUP BY** because its **very slow** :(

So if you want to get the these Values you shoud use:

First Value:

```
SELECT * FROM <SERIES> GROUP BY * ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1
```

Last Value:

```
SELECT * FROM <SERIES> GROUP BY * ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
```

Don't delete the GROUP BY * because then it could be possible that you get unexpected values then.

Comment: Do you have any explanation on what these unexpected values look like and why they show up?

Comment: -1 for [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt). If you want to assert that something is broken, provide a demonstration of the brokenness - not a vague and untestable assertion that *"it could be possible that you get unexpected values "*.

Comment: Running InfluxDB 1.7.9, this query returns more than a single result for a table/measurement. Evidently this is only good for a series.

Comment: Just checked with "EXPLAIN" and using "LAST()" with "WHERE time > now() - 1h" seems better/faster then using "ORDER BY ... LIMIT" even with "GROUP BY" - the latter used all the shards.

Comment: So using FIRST() in InfluxDB version > 0.8 is fast?

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT last(value) FROM response_times WHERE time > now() - 1h;
```

That should return the last value of the column.

However, if you want you can split up the sequence in smaller pieces and select the last value. For instance:

```
 SELECT last(value) FROM response_times WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(60s);
```

It will split up the sequence in 60-second fragments and will pick up for each fragment the latest value.

Comment: This will not give you the last value if it's longer than x ago.

Answer (score 7):

If like me you are looking for the same feature but with the **Flux DSL** (influx 2).

You can use the **tail** function https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/tail/

```
(...)
  |> tail(n: 1)
```

The **last** function didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 4):

here is a concrete sample, suppose we have data:

```
> select *,tag from measurement
name: measurement
time                 field_1    tag_1
----                 -------    ------
2019-05-15T03:07:52Z 100      A
2019-05-15T03:07:52Z 101      B
2019-05-15T03:09:52Z 100      A
2019-05-15T03:09:52Z 101      B
```

and you would like to take the last two columns(latest records per tag_1),
then you can do this:

```
> select last(field_1),* from measurement group by *
name: measurement
tags: tag_1=A
time                 last     field_1 
----                 ----    ------- 
2019-05-15T03:09:52Z 100        100     

name: measurement
tags: tag_1=B
time                 last  field_1 
----                 ----  ------- 
2019-05-15T03:09:52Z 101    101
```

and also the visualization on grafana, it'll always show the last records per tag
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM <SERIES> ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: DESC for last value. ASC with LIMIT 1 will return the first.

Comment: For long series, this is also much slower than selecting `WHERE time > now - ...`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug or any issue about LIMIT. Yes there is one, but it's about SLIMIT (Series Limit). LIMIT can be safely used for getting *first n* records.

So in short, the syntax for LIMIT:

```
SELECT_clause [INTO_clause] FROM_clause [WHERE_clause] [GROUP_BY_clause] [ORDER_BY_clause] LIMIT <N>
```

the syntax for SLIMIT:

```
SELECT_clause [INTO_clause] FROM_clause [WHERE_clause] GROUP BY *[,time(<time_interval>)] [ORDER_BY_clause] SLIMIT <N>
```

You see that GROUP BY clause is [ optional ] in LIMIT.

For detailed explanation about usages of LIMIT and SLIMIT, here is [version 1.5 document](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/data_exploration/#the-limit-and-slimit-clauses).
And here is the [ongoing issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7571) about SLIMIT.