# influxdb query last row of all series in a measurement

Tags: metrics, influxdb

I trying to find a way to get the most recent row for each serie in a measurement.

for example:

Assuming the series in `results` measurement are:

```
> select series from test_result
results,service=MyService,team=A
result,service=MyService,team=B
test_result,service=MyService,team=C
```

and the rows in a given time frame are:

```
> select * from test_result order by time desc

time                service     team       status duration
----                -------     ----       ------ --------
1523370939000000000 MyService A 1      300
1523370940000000000 MyService B 1      300
1523370941000000000 MyService A 1      300
1523370941000000000 MyService C 1      300
1523371748000000000 MyService A 1      300
1523371749000000000 MyService B 1      300
1523371750000000000 MyService B 1      300
1523371754000000000 MyService A 1      300
```

I would expect the query to return the first, second and fourth rows.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this addresses your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193898/influxdb-getting-only-last-value-in-query

Comment: thanks danS this will returns the last row for the entire measurement. I would like to get the last row for all combinations of the tags (series). so if the measurement has 50 combinations of tags, it would return 50 rows back.

Comment: Adding a `GROUP BY service, team` should do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Katy from Influx Staff who answered the question:

> To separate the series, you can add GROUP BY *, which will give you
>   the results separated by series. Then you can add aggregates to your
>   query, like LAST. For example: SELECT LAST(field_name),* from
>   test_result GROUP BY *
>
> Keep in mind that your fields are also a factor here. You can use *
>   without specifying a field, but there’s room for error there. It’s
>   better to specify a field if you know what you need.